# the coordinate ring of a quasiprojective variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [$\mathbb{A}^{2}$ not isomorphic to affine space minus the origin](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122821/mathbba2-not-isomorphic-to-affine-space-minus-the-origin)

Hello I'm using the book Basic algebraic geometry I of Shafarevich.

***Definitions:***
I'm very complicated with the computation of the coordinate ring of a quasiprojective variety. In the affine case, this ring it´s easier to compute, because (using the notation of Shafarevich) if X it´s my closed set, the it´s ring of coordinates it's $k[T]/U_X$ ( at least could be something explicit). But in the projective case.
Given $X \subset P^n$ a quasiprojective variety, the ring of coordinates denoted also by $k[X]$ is defined as the set of all functions of the form $ f=P/Q $ where P,Q homogeneous polynomials of the same degree , and $ Q(x) \ne 0 $ for every x $\in X$.

**Problem:**
For example, I have to prove that the quasiprojective variety $
{\rm A}^2  - \left\{ {\left( {0,0} \right)} \right\}
$ is not isomorphic to an affine variety. And the hint of the problem it's to compute $k[X]$ and showing that it has a proper ideal $
J \subseteq k\left[ X \right]
$, such that defines a nonempty set.

But I have no idea , what can I do with this abstract (at least for me now) $k[X]$. 
Sorry for this stupid question

Comment: Dear Matias, your question is not stupid at all, but it has already been answered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/122826/3217)