# Open subschemes of affine schemes are affine?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm reading Hartshorne, and was wondering if this was true:

> Let $A$ be a ring and let $U$ be an open subset of $Spec(A)$. Let $S$ be the set of elements of $A$ not in any prime of $U$. Then $S$ is multiplicatively closed and $\mathcal{O}_A|_U \cong Spec(A[S^{-1}])$ as schemes.

It seems like you would certainly want open subsets of affine schemes to be affine, but I can't seem to find a proof in Hartshorne. Perhaps it's too "obvious" to bother proving, but here is a supposed proof:

$S$ is obviously multiplicatively closed. The map $A \rightarrow A[S^{-1}]$ induces an inclusion-preserving bijection between primes not meeting $S$ and primes of $A[S^{-1}]$. I claim that the primes in $U$ are precisely those that do not meet $S$: if $U^c = V(\mathfrak{a})$, then we show that some element of $S$ lies in $\mathfrak{a}$. If not, then each element of $\mathfrak{a}$ is not in $S$, and so $\mathfrak{a} \subset \bigcup \big\{\mathfrak{p} : \mathfrak{p} \in U\big\}.$ A result of commutative algebra (Atiyah-MacDonald Prop 1.11) then has $\mathfrak{a} \subseteq \mathfrak{p}$ for some $\mathfrak{p}$, a contradiction. Hence any prime not in $U$ contains $\mathfrak{a}$ and so meets $S$. The primes that are in $U$ do not meet $S$ by definition.

This gives a homeomorphism $\phi:U \rightarrow Spec(A[S^{-1}])$ on the level of spaces. We now build an isomorphism of schemes. Let $W$ be an open set of $A[S^{-1}]$. The correspondence of ideals gives an open set in $U$, which we will denote $V$. Suppose $F:W \rightarrow \bigsqcup_{\mathfrak{p} \in W} A[S^{-1}]_\mathfrak{p}$ is locally a fraction. Pick $\mathfrak{p} \in W$. Then let $f = \frac{a}{s} \in A[S^{-1}]$ satisfy $\mathfrak{p} \in D(f) \subseteq W$, and choose $b \in A$ such that $F(\mathfrak{q}) = \frac{b}{f} \in A[S^{-1}]_\mathfrak{q}$ for each $\mathfrak{q} \in D(f)$. Now, if $\mathfrak{p} \in D(f)$, then $\mathfrak{p}\cap A$ does not contain $a$, and conversely. So $D(f)$ is sent to the open set $D(a)$ in $A$. So if we define $G$ on $V$ by $G(\mathfrak{p}\cap A) = F(\mathfrak{p}) \in A[S^{-1}]_\mathfrak{p} \cong A_{\mathfrak{p}\cap A}$, then on $D(a)$, we have $G(\mathfrak{p}\cap A) = F(\mathfrak{p}) = \frac{b}{f} = \frac{sb}{a} \in A_{\mathfrak{p} \cap A}$. So $G$ is locally a fraction, and so this defines $\Gamma(A[S^{-1}], W) \rightarrow \Gamma(A,V)$ and so produces a morphism of schemes. On stalks, this morphism is an isomorphism, and so the morphism itself is an isomorphism of schemes.

---

Does this proof look correct? I'm always afraid I've missed something subtle with these things.

EDIT: I have figured out where the proof is wrong. The cited Atiyah-Macdonald proposition only holds for finite unions of prime ideals.

Comment: On non-separated schemes, you don't generally have that the intersection of affines is affine. In particular the intersection is contained in both affines, but is not affine.

Comment: One good example when open subsets of affine schemes are affine is when the underlying ring is a Valuation ring. So for a Noetherian example you can just take $X=Spec R$ where $R$ is a DVR (albeit such a Scheme has dimension $1$ only)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It turns out to be wrong in general! (it was a surprise to me too) It's true for (noetherian) curves, though.

The simplest example I know is the affine punctured plane. Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, and let $A = \mathbb{A}^2_k$ be the affine plane over $k$: that is, $\mathop{\mathrm{Spec}} k[x,y]$.

Then if $O$ is the origin, $Z = A \setminus \{ O \} $ is **not** an affine scheme. However, it is a scheme, and can be written as the union of $A \setminus X$ and $A \setminus Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are the $x-$ and $y-$ axes respectively.

The easiest way to see that it's not affine is that $\mathcal{O}(Z) \cong k[x,y]$! This can be computed by the union I described above:

- $A \setminus X \cong \mathop{\mathrm{Spec}} k[x,y,x^{-1}]$
- $A \setminus Y \cong \mathop{\mathrm{Spec}} k[x,y,y^{-1}]$
- $A \setminus (X \cup Y) \cong \mathop{\mathrm{Spec}} k[x,y,x^{-1},y^{-1}]$

Therefore, $\mathcal{O}(A \setminus O) = \mathcal{O}(A \setminus (X \cap Y))$ is the pullback of the diagram

$$ \begin{matrix} & & k[x,y,x^{-1}] \\ & & \downarrow \\ k[x,y,y^{-1}] &\rightarrow& k[x,y,x^{-1},y^{-1}] \end{matrix} $$

Both arrows are inclusions, so this means we have

$$\mathcal{O}(A \setminus O) = k[x,y,y^{-1}] \cap k[x,y,x^{-1}] = k[x,y] $$

Comment: For completeness, the proof that $Z$ is not affine is finished by using the 1-1 correspondence of affine schemes and rings, the coordinate ring of $\mathbb{A}^2_k$ is $k[x,y]$, and $Z$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^2_k$.

Comment: See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/122826/3217)

Comment: @Cantlog: Thanks. I was *really* sure, but don't do this stuff enough to really feel confident that I know all the edge cases well.

Comment: Dear Hurkyl, sorry, my comment should be just "This is true for noetherian affine schemes of dimension 1, see [this lemma in Stacks project](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/09N9)". In fact, this is essentiallt the only case the statement is true. Namely, if $X$ is a noetherian of dimension $\ge 2$, then there is a non-empty open subscheme which is not affine. It is enough to remove a closed point of maximal codimension (as in your example).

Comment: You should probably mention why the global sections being $k[x,y]$ is a contradiction. There are multiple ways to do this. For example, define $(\varphi,\varphi^\sharp):(\mathbb{A}^2,\mathcal{O})\to (\mathbb{A}^2-\{0\},\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^2-\{0\}})$ defined by $\varphi$  being inclusion, and $\varphi^\sharp_U$ being restriction. It's not hard to show that the map on global sections is an isomorphism which, if both were affine, would imply that $(\varphi,\varphi^\sharp)$ is an isomorphism, which is ridiculous since $\varphi$ isn't surjective. Or you could do some trick about how the

Comment: vanishing sets of max ideals of the global sections of $\mathbb{A}^2$ are always non-empty, but this is not true for $\mathbb{A}^2-\{0\}$.