# Showing that affine space minus one point is not isomorphic to the affine space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

I want to prove that $\mathbb{A}^1$ is not isomorphic to $X =\mathbb{A}^1 \setminus \{p\}$ where $p \in \mathbb{A}^1$.

Assuming I can take $p = 0$ by change of coordinates, at first I tried proving that $X$ is not an affine variety, but I found in another post (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/880955) that it actually is.

So now I think I should use the function rings but I'm not sure how to proceed...

Comment: Can you write down what the rings of global functions are on each of these? Are they the same? Why or why not?

Comment: About your linked post : $\mathbb{A}^1 \setminus \{p\}$ is not an affine variety, but it is isomorphic to an affine variety $X \subset \mathbb{A}^n$ (if $p$ is a single point then $n=2$ and the isomorphism is $f(x) = (x-p, \frac{1}{x-p})$ where $X  = \{ (y,z) \in K^2, yz = 1\}$)

Comment: Also $ (0,0)$ is a point in $\mathbb{A}^2$ not  $\mathbb{A}^1$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Right, show that $k[x]$ and $k[x,x^{-1}]$ are not isomorphic. You can do this by showing that the latter ring has no single element that generates it (as a ring). I think it is helpful to keep track of min and max degrees of the terms of an element of $k[x, 1/x]$. You can first show that $x + 1/x$ doesn't generate $k[x,1/x]$, the figure out why this didn't work and generalize.

Alternative approach (cleaner): You can show that the only ring maps from $k[x,1/x] \to k[x]$ have to send $x$ and $1/x$ to units, and thus these maps can't be surjective.